# Visual Studio 2013 professional installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I am trying to install VS 2013 professional on my system (Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 - 64 bit)
but getting following error.
[image]

I restarted the system but it didn't solve my issue.

Please find error log at ::
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67Ts22A1TPZNllJeWFOcmgyaXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the logs it states `ErrorMessage: Service 'SQL Server VSS Writer' (SQLWriter) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.` did you run the installation as Admin?

Comment: Yes..I ran it as admin

Comment: try starting the service manually from the Services.msc, looks like it installed ok, it just cant start the services, could be just UAC being overzealous

Comment: Its not able to start giving error like service didn't respond to start or control request in timely manner.

Comment: Check the windows EventLogs for the ServiceManager error, may give you more clues